# Automaticaly update data from API calling API once React JS

Tags: reactjs, api

I'm trying to find a solution to automatically update the API data with one call in React.

What I want is to get the score and the time from the match live without calling api for this to update or refresh the page.

I added the function setInterval, it works properly but will call the API every time and I don't want to call the API every second.

My code is

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import './App.css';

function EvenimenteMaine() {

    useEffect(() => {
     // setInterval(() => {
        fetchItems();
    //  }, 1000)
    
    },[]);

    const OPTIONS = {
        method : 'GET',
        headers : {
            'X-RapidAPI-Host' : 'api-football-v1.p.rapidapi.com',
            'X-RapidAPI-Key' : '###'
        }
    };
    
    const [fixtures, setFixtures] = useState([]);

    const fetchItems = async () => {
        const data = await fetch(
            'https://api-football-v1.p.rapidapi.com/v2/fixtures/id/232860' , OPTIONS
            );
        const fixtures = await data.json();
        const teamData = fixtures.api && fixtures.api.fixtures.length > 0 ? fixtures.api.fixtures : [];

        console.log(fixtures);
        setFixtures(teamData);
    }


  return (
    <div>
      {fixtures.slice(0,10).map(fixture => (
        <div>
        <div>{fixture.elapsed}</div>
        <div><span>{fixture.goalsHomeTeam}</span> - <span>{fixture.goalsAwayTeam}</span></div>

        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

export default EvenimenteMaine;
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: `What i want is to get the score and the time from the match live without calling api for this to update or refresh the page` Sorry I don't understand - so you want to fire request once and then store data update page?

Comment: i want to fire request once and store the score and update it every minute, so i can receive the score and automaticaly update every 1 minute. but i want o request once the api

Comment: But as I score is changed on server side? So to get current score you will need to do request to the server

Comment: so any site that gives you informations about an match is doing the request to api each second ?

Comment: Okey so there are two options to achieve having current scores: One is to do request in interval or write websocket connection. I think most of live score websites are built on websoockets

Comment: It's better to use Web Sockets instead of calling API on intervals. you can see socket.io

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this. If you want to fetch updated data from the server-side then you need to make an API call. How will the client or your app know that the score/data has been updated if you won't make the API call? So I believe, if you want to fetch updated data, you have to make API calls.